# selecting max record in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, max

I have a table of multiple transactions. I am trying to get the row of the last transaction.
I am using the following:

```
select n.AccountNumber, max(PostDate), f.TransAmt 
from mp_cycle n, fintrans f
where n.AccountNumber = f.AccountNumber
and TransCode >= '50'
and TransCode <= '59'
group by n.AccountNumber
```

This is returning the last date for a particular account, but the TransAmt is not for the same record.

ie:

```
Acct #  Date   Amt
1       1/1    10.00
1       1/2    11.00
1       1/3    12.00
2       1/2    20.00
2       1/3    21.00
2       1/4    22.00
```

My select will return the last date for each account, so 1/3 for act # 1 and 1/4 for act # 2, but the Amt field is not the amt that goes with that record.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this problem, one is by joining extra subquery which separate gets the latest `PostDate` for every `AccountNumber`. The result of the subquery will then be joined on the other table provided that it should match on two columns: `AccountNumber` and `PostDate`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    mp_cycle a
        INNER JOIN fintrans b
            ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  AccountNumber, MAX(PostDate) max_date
            FROM    fintrans 
            GROUP   BY AccountNumber
        ) c ON  b.AccountNumber = c.AccountNumber AND
                b.PostDate = c.max_date
-- WHERE    ..your conditions here..
```

Comment: I modified the select at the top to only select the 3 fields I need and added the where clause where specified. This seems to work well. Thanks!